# Adding more information onto the $user object in drupal?

Tags: drupal

How would I go about loading my own data onto the $user object upon login of a user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[hook_user()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_user/6) probably has the functionality you need

```
custommodule_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL){
    global $user;
    if($op=='login'){
        $user->custommodule['data']='some stuff';
    }
}
```